# Composite ID and its generation in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I want use custom class like ID

```
@javax.persistence.Embeddable  
class ObjectID impements Serializable{  
private Long value;    
  //setters, getters and other  
 }
```

Here is mapped class

```
@Entity  
@IdClass(ObjectID.class)  
public class Country implements Serializable   
{  
   @Id  
   @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "id"))  
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "CountrySequenceGenerator",  
                       sequenceName = "lab_country_seq")  
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  
                    generator = "CountryCountryGenerator")  
   private ObjectID value;
  // setters, getters, fields  
}
```

Doesn't work. Value wasn't generated. Any ideas, how can I generate ID for composite-id?

Comment: What is CountryCountryGenerator?

Comment: "composite id" with a single field ? how is that composite? Composite id is with multiple fields

Answer (score 0):

Id class has to be Serializable and implements hashCode and equals

Comment: I have all this in me ObjectID class.

Comment: See [Composite ID and its generation in JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9632942/651140)